# Behavior of a pointer to an element of `slice` after the `slice` had been appended to

Tags: pointers, go, slice

I am wondering what is the behavior of a pointer to an element of `slice` after the `slice` had been appended to, for example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    my_slice := []int {3}

    silly_ptr := &my_slice[0]
    // Do we know that silly_ptr points to value equal 3
    // all the time? (If we don't explicitly change it).

    fmt.Printf("%p\n", silly_ptr)
    fmt.Println(*silly_ptr)

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        my_slice = append(my_slice, i)
    }

    silly_ptr_2 := &my_slice[0]

    fmt.Printf("%p\n", silly_ptr_2)
    fmt.Println(*silly_ptr_2)
}
```

Produces: (no surprises)

```
0xc20800a200
3
0xc20805a000
3
```

I know that when appending to dynamic array, at certain points we have repopulate the entire array, and therefore memory address of the original array elements is not reliable. To the best of my knowledge similar code is valid in `c++`, but `silly_ptr` could be pointing to anything. `rust` does not allow mutating a `vector` if it is being borrowed, so the above logic would not compile.

But what about `Go`? I know that by `escape analysis` it is valid to return a pointer to a local variable, the variable would be just created on the heap for you. My intuition tells me that the same logic applies in the above case. The memory location where `silly_ptr` is pointing to will not be repopulated, and hence will always store `3` (if we don't explictly change it). Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not always store 3.

Go has memory management. As long as there is an active pointer to an underlying array for a slice, the underlying array is pinned, it will not be garbage collected. If you have a pointer to an element of an underlying array, you can change the value of the element. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func pin() *int {
    s := []int{3}
    fmt.Println(&s[0])
    a := &s[0]
    s = append(s, 7)
    fmt.Println(&s[0])
    return a
}

func main() {
    a := pin()
    fmt.Println(a, *a)
    *a = 42
    fmt.Println(a, *a)
}
```

Output:

```
0xc82000a340
0xc82000a360
0xc82000a340 3
0xc82000a340 42
```

A slice descriptor contains a pointer to an underlying array so you can see something similar with a slice. For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func pin() []int {
    s := []int{3}
    fmt.Println(&s[0])
    d := s
    s = append(s, 7)
    fmt.Println(&s[0])
    return d
}

func main() {
    d := pin()
    fmt.Println(&d[0], d)
    d[0] = 42
    fmt.Println(&d[0], d)
}
```

Output:

```
0xc82000a340
0xc82000a360
0xc82000a340 [3]
0xc82000a340 [42]
```

Comment: I should've been more clear, I don't want to consider a case where we explicitly change the value where the pointer points to. But you say: "As long as there is an active pointer to an underlying array for a slice, the underlying array is pinned, it will not be garbage collected." This seems to answer my question: `silly_ptr` will always point to value equal 3, unless we explicitly change that value, right? Do you know of any good resources on the topic?

Comment: @Akavall: My answer showed that you can safely use the pointer to both read and write the element value. The text for the Go garbage collection project is: The Garbage Collection Handbook: The Art of Automatic Memory Management (Chapman & Hall/CRC Applied Algorithms and Data Structures series) R. Jones, A. Hosking, E. Moss.